# ExtJs HTML Component Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs

I have built a custom HTML component in extJS by specifying the html value of a panel. I am unable to attach the event handlers to the element (or they are somehow not firing). However, I am able to do other things on the component like hide, append etc.

```
Ext.select('#toFieldDiv').on('click',function() {
    alert("something");
});  //Doesn't Work

Ext.select('#toFieldDiv').hide('slow');  //Works
```

Any idea?

Here is my component definition:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    x: 70,
    y: 0,
    html: "<div id=\"toFieldDiv\" class=\"to-field\"> </div>"
}
```

I have even tried the same with jQuery. Again the hide works, but not the click.

Comment: I don't see a click event for panels in ExtJS.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to build a hotmail/facebook type "to" field for an email form. For that, I was placing the email ids inside a div element (built as xtype panel). Do you have anything in mind which provides click events where I can place email ids dynamically?

Comment: I added an answer with an working implementation and provided a link to a Sencha article on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem. The problem was not in this part of the code (just as I imagined). The event should and does work because it is just a normal click event on a div element.

The problem was because another text field was getting superimposed on the div element, thereby passing the click events to the TextField instead of the div element.

Answer (score 6):

I found an [example and explanation](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?32820-Panel-onClick-event) of why this doesn't work out of the box on the Sencha forums. I implemented a suggested solution below.

```
 Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Hello',
    width: 200,
    html: '<p>World!</p>',
    listeners: {render: function(c){c.el.on('click', function() { alert('onclick');});}},
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ExtJS 4?

First, have you tried "Ext.get" instead of "Ext.select"?

If you are using ExtJS 4, there is an easier way of dong this actually. 4 lets you set events on the "el" of the widgets.

Comment: so does using "Ext.get('toFieldDiv')" fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

For Extjs 3.3.1, you can use Ext.getCmp() instead.

Here Ext.select() returns CompositeElementLite/CompositeElement and these components do not extend from Observable. So it does not support binding with on().

Ext.getCmp() returns Ext.Component, so it can.